# How to make a multi line if statement in your own programming language visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Ok so i am making my own programming language in visual basic and im using Arrays to make the commands. right now i have:

```
 if Array(0) = "if" then
    if array(4) = "then" then
       if Array(1) = Array(3) then
          if Array(5) = "println." then
             console.writeline(stringtypedin)
          end if
       end if
    end if
 end if
```

but what i want to happen is to make the if statement and let println be on a different line. dont know if this is possible but i thought i would ask

Comment: It is possible, you should look at how [parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser_generator) and [lexical analyser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) do it. Building it from scratch is a big job. If your if statement is true, you need to run everyline until you hit the proper end if.

Comment: I think that the biggest problem is this line: `if Array(1) = Array(3) then`. How do you expect that to work exactly?

Comment: @sstan that statement is fine thats saying that if enter 5 = 5 then its gonna say true thats not what im worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i know i have this tagged as an answer but i think i have the solution and will update you to see if it works but let me know if you think this will work

```
if array(0) = "if" then
 if array(4) = "then" then
  if Array(1) = Array(3) then
   booleanvar = true
  end if
 end if
else
 booleanvar = false
end if

if booleanvar = true then
 do until array(0) = "end."
  if array(0) = "println." then
   console.writeline(stringtypedin);
 loop
end if
```

with this i should be able to say

```
 if 5 = 5 then
  println. hello
 end.
```